# Como Solucionar Erro de Importação do github3 no Python?

Tags: python, github, importação

Estou tentando executar um código em python que necessita de utilizar o github3, porém recebo o seguinte erro:

```
    Nabucodonosor-z400:~/Modelos/gthbmining/rc/loaddata$ python3 main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vitor-avancini/Modelos/gthbmining/rc/loaddata/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from loader import Loader
  File "/home/vitor-avancini/Modelos/gthbmining/rc/loaddata/loader.py", line 1, in <module>
    from github3 import login, authorize
ImportError: cannot import name 'authorize' from 'github3' (/home/vitor-avancini/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/github3/__init__.py)
```

No loader.py eu importo o github3 da seguinte maneira:

```
from github3 import login, authorize
```

E então na main.py chamo o loader assim:

```
from loader import Loader
```

Como posso corrigir o erro?

Comment: Qual é a versão do github3 está usando?

Comment: Python 3.10.6 @Woss

Comment: Essa é a versão do python, mas qual é a versão da biblioteca?